# Lie algebra of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: manifolds, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. How do I show that Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is given by $$\mathfrak{g} = \{ B \in \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{R}) : \forall t \in \mathbb{R}, e^{tB} \in G \} $$

$\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{R})$ is the Lie algebra of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What is your definition of "the Lie algebra of" a Lie group?

Comment: I think I got it.. $e^B$ is invertible for every $B \in \mathfrak{gl}(n)$..

Comment: I don't understand what that comment is supposed to mean